# remove empty object in nested object in javascript using es6

Tags: javascript, json

Kindly help me in this to delete key/value in nested object

```
INPUT: {"a":{"b":{},"c":{"d":true},"e":{}}}

Output: {"a":{"c":{"d":true}}}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you want to delete empty objects in the input ?